# Linux: how do I add few seconds to an existing timestamp bash?

Tags: bash

For example :, I have a tile as veritable like: tt="Thu 09/22/2016 11:03:55 AM" and I need to add few seconds to this time stamp in bash 
current status  :Thu 09/22/2016 11:03:55

requested status: Thu 09/22/2016 11:04:02 + var 
in this case the var will be 7 seconds

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Use the date command.

Comment: thank for replay ,date return the current date as i know .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GNU `date` command to parse your date string into epoch seconds, then add your time difference, then use `date` again to convert epoch seconds back to human readable form.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD_TT="Thu 09/22/2016 11:03:55 AM"
OFFSET=7

EPOCH=$( date --date="$OLD_TT" "+%s" )
NEW_EPOCH=$(( $EPOCH + $OFFSET ))

NEW_TT=$( date --date=\@$NEW_EPOCH "+%a %m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" )

echo "Old Date : $TT"
echo "New Date : $NEW_TT"
```

**Output**

```
Old Date : Thu 09/22/2016 11:03:55 AM
New Date : Thu 09/22/2016 11:04:02 AM
```

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, you can avoid an external process by using `printf -v NEW_TT '%(%a %m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p)T' "$NEW_EPOCH"`.